# Message: [Warning]Animated:'useNativeDriver' was not specified.This is a required option

Tags: react-native, navigation, warnings

I am using react-native 0.62.2. And I have no animation in my codebase, but still I am getting this warning for the useNativeDriver.

I just used react-native-router-flux for the navigation and I am getting this warning. Is there any solution. Here is my code:

```
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';

 forgotPasswordHandler(){
   //change to forgot password screen
   Actions.forgotPassword();
 }

render(){

   return(
    <View>
       <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.forgotPasswordHandler.bind(this)}>
           <Text style={styles.forgotbuttonStyle}>Forgot your password?</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
   );
}
```

When I go to the forget password screen, I run the following code:

```
render(){
    return(
         <View>
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> Actions.popTo('login')}>
              <View style={styles.buttonbgStyle}>
                  <Text style={styles.btnTextStyle}>Back</Text>
              </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
     );
}
```

My Router Component Screen is :

```
const RouterComponent = ()=>{

    return(
        <Router>
            <Scene key="root">
                <Scene key="login" component={LoginScreen} hideNavBar={true} initial/>
                <Scene key="forgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} hideNavBar={true}/>
            </Scene>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

Can anyone help me to fix the warning

Comment: It appears to be a warning bubbling up from `react-native-router-flux`. Do you use the most recent version?

Comment: The warning is from `Actions` you've imported from 'react-native-router-flux'. It has nothing to do with your code. You're using `react-native-router-flux` to navigate through different screens? Why not use the props.navigation ?

Comment: is there any solutions for using the Actions